# How to get duplicate values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an object array and I want to get the objects which has the same title to an array and object with same _id cannot get repeated. How can I get those are there any methods to get it?

```
products=[{_id:1234,title:'carrot',price:90},{_id:345,title:'Beans',price:100},{_id:789,title:'carrot',price:100}]
```

result should be

```
result=[{_id:1234,title:'carrot',price:90},{_id:789,title:'carrot',price:100}]
```

Comment: so which object should be in final result

Comment: As in the above I updated the question with the output I expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is posible by using reduce and find methods. First dismiss the duplicated objects with the findIndex; then group the objects inside a parent object, which use the title as property, by using the reduce method:

```
let products=[{_id:1234,title:'carrot',price:90},{_id:345,title:'Beans',price:100},{_id:789,title:'carrot',price:100}]
let grouped = products.reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) => {
    if (arr.findIndex(obj => obj._id === cur._id) === i) {
        if (!(cur.title in acc)) {
            acc[cur.title] = []
        }
        acc[cur.title].push(cur)
    }
    return acc
}, {})
console.log(grouped)
```

Result:

```
{
  "carrot": [
    {
      "_id": 1234,
      "title": "carrot",
      "price": 90
    },
    {
      "_id": 789,
      "title": "carrot",
      "price": 100
    }
  ],
  "Beans": [
    {
      "_id": 345,
      "title": "Beans",
      "price": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

References: [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) / [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)